# Menu is not showing up on mobile in WordPress Edea Theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem. The menu is not showing up on mobile / tablet on http://bmnr.thedesgineryouneed.com . I tried to find the code problem but I couldn't. Can you help me ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the top margin of the `#btn_div`. it has minus top margin so it is hidden.